# 404 error when switching between stores when in a category on magento

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

My magento website has 5 store views. When we are in a product in English and select French, it redirects correctly and show the product in French. But when it comes to categories, it doesn't work at all.

I'm on a category with the url http://myweb.com/en/body-care, if I change to the Spanish view, it doesn't redirect to the url "../cuidado-del-cuerpo" it just goes to to http://myweb.com/es/body-care and shows a 404 error (it changes the 'en' for 'es', but doesn't change the last part of the url).

The rewrite is not defined on the URL Rewrite Management section. I have 5 categories and 5 store views, so it's not a good idea to create the rewrites rules manually.

How can I solve this? Why the rewrite rules were not written when we created/modified the url of each category?

Comment: Maybe you missed/did wrong step #1 from the [Creating Multiple Online Storefronts Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part1/)?

Comment: Hi, Zyava. Well, that's not the case. There are not really different storefronts but storeviews. In this case we don't need to create a new root category, we only need to change the name/url of each category for each store view. I'm not sure, but I think that at the beginning it worked, but when I changed later the url of some of the categories, the redirections didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you check if the urlkey is definable on store view level, or if it is set to website level? That way, you can only create 1 url key for EN and ES. You need it to be at store view level, do define 2 separate values.

2) Is there something in your error log? (and is your error log turned on?) Normally url rewrites are created automatically for each store view. If not, you may need to manually reindex.

It's hard to give further advice, since the problem could be anywhere (conflicting module? bad code?)