# Magento multilanguage - double change in language resuts in 404 (or how to change language within stores not views)

Tags: url, magento, seo, http-status-code-404, multilingual

I have a problem with a magento installation. I used Magento ver. 1.5.0.1, community edition to develop this website http://cissmarket.com/.

The problem appears when I change the language from the EU version to French and after that to German. The change to french is ok, but when in the same page i change to German i receive a 404 error. Also this is generation 404 errors in the Google webmaster tools and when i try for example to take this link and paste it in the browser it gives me also a 404 error. I have there some 50 products and ~550 404 errors in Google Webmaster tools. I understand that the problem is from what I described.

Moreover I have a SEO problem since I have this page in french:

http://cissmarket.com/de/cartouches-refilables.html

And when I switch to the german version of the website it takes me to this link

http://cissmarket.com/de/cartouches-refilables.html?___from_store=fr (if i try now to switch to uk I will get the 404 mentioned above)

instead of going to this one:

http://cissmarket.com/de/nachfullpatronen.html

Already checked this [404 error when switching between stores when in a category on magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322121/404-error-when-switching-between-stores-when-in-a-category-on-magento) but it does not relate to my problem.

About settings:

- I use the caching service and also I did index all the content.
- The product or category I am trying to access is available and set active for all the languages.
- System > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls is set
  to yes.
- System > General > Web > Search Engines Optimization > Use Web Server
  Rewrites is set to yes.
- No other changes has been made to the .htaccess file except for the
  ones that the system itself made.

So to conclude: the problem is the 404 given by 2 succesive changes of the language and the bad url address when I switch from one page to another.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE: tried this http://www.activo.com/how-to-avoid-the-___from_store-query-parameter-when-switching-store-views-in-magento but it results in a 404 at the first language change

**Edit #1:**

Found the problem: file languages.phtml contained this code `<?php echo str_replace ("/fr/","/de/",$_lang->getCurrentUrl()); ?>` and actually did replace only the language code and not the whole url according to the corresponding translation.

So applied to this

> http://cissmarket.com/fr/cartouches-refilables.html

it will return

> http://cissmarket.com/de/cartouches-refilables.html

So does anyone know how to get the corresponding URL of the current page for the other languages available in the store?

Edit #2 (using @Vinai solution):

It works on the product pages but not on the category yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing in the native Magento as far as I know.
That said, you can use the following code to get the current page URL for each store.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$requestPath = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->escape(
    trim(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestString(), '/')
);

$select = $resource->getConnection('default_read')->select()
    ->from(array('c' => $resource->getTableName('core/url_rewrite')), '')
    ->where('c.request_path=?', $requestPath)
    ->where('c.store_id=?', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->joinInner(
        array('t' => $resource->getTableName('core/url_rewrite')),
        "t.category_id=c.category_id AND t.product_id=c.product_id AND t.id_path=c.id_path",
        array('t.store_id', 't.request_path')
    );
$storeUrls = (array) $resource->getConnection('default_read')
    ->fetchPairs($select);
```

This will give you an array with the array key being the store IDs and the array values being the request path **after** the Magento base URL, e.g. assuming your French store has the ID 1 and the German one has the ID 2, you would get:

```
Array
(
    [1] => cartouches-refilables.html
    [2] => nachfullpatronen.html
)
```

Then, in the `foreach` loop where the URL for each store is output, use

```
<?php $url = isset($storeUrls[$_lang->getId()]) ? $_lang->getUrl($storeUrls[$_lang->getId()]) : $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>
```

The call to `$_lang->getUrl()` will add the base URL, so you will get the full URL for each store (e.g. http://cissmarket.com/de/nachfullpatronen.html). If no store view value is found in the `core_url_rewrite` table it will revert to the default behaviour.

You still need the `___store=fr` query parameter because otherwise Magento will think you are trying to access the new path in the context of the old store. Luckily, the `getUrl()` call an the store model adds that for you automatically.

The code querying the database can be anywhere of course (since its PHP), even in the template, but please don't put it there. **The correct place to have code that access the database is a resource model**. I suggest you create a resource model and put it in a method there.

Comment: I will check that and come back with an answer! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It works which is fine but not on the category page but only on the product page. I tried the simple version of output with `print_r($storeUrls);` and on the category page the array is empty, however on the product page it returns the correct array of elements as you have said.

Answer (score 3):

I've found an ugly patch until a better approach comes up.

In the admin section, i've added the following javascript inside the wysiwyg in **CMS > PAGES > (My 404 pages)** (at the beginning of the wysiwyg) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
var lang = "en";
var rooturl = "{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}"
var url = document.location.href;
if(!(url.match("/"+lang+"/")))
{
  var newUrl = url.replace(rooturl , rooturl+lang+"/" );
  window.location.href = newUrl;
}
// ]]></script>
```

*(Note: you need to do this for all of your translated 404 pages. In each 404 page you need to modify **lang="en"** for your storeview url value)*

Because the wysiwyg (tiny_mce) does not allow javascript to be threated, you'll have to modify **js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tinymce/setup.js**. Add the following code under line 97 (under "var settings = "):

```
extended_valid_elements : 'script[language|type|src]',
```

Comment: Linking to your own website in this manner may end up getting your post deleted as spam. I am removing the link, as your answer seems fine without it. Please *do not* add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 1.7.0.2 and 1.8.0.0 this is the bugfix:

Starting from line 251 of /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php

:

```
Mage::app()->getCookie()->set(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME, $currentStore->getCode(), true);

// endur 02-03-2013 fix for missed store code

// $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl(). '/' . $this->getRequestPath();

if (Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/use_store') && $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()>getCode()) { 
    $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl(). '/' . $storeCode . '/' .$this->getRequestPath();
    } else {
      $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl(). '/' . $this->getRequestPath();
    }

// endur 02-03-2013 end
```

Make sure to create a custom copy of the file in:
/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php or:
/app/code/local/YourTheme/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php

[source:](http://www.bennewitz.com/devel/magento-shopper-theme-and-vto/#comment-12516)

Answer (score 0):

Here a another solution for this problem. Just add this code after "$this->load($pathInfo, 'request_path');" in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php:

```
        if (!$this->getId() && !isset($_GET['___from_store'])) {
            $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('default_read');
            $result = $db->query('select store_id from core_url_rewrite WHERE request_path = "' . $pathInfo . '"');
            if ($result) {
                $storeIds = array();
                if($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $storeId = $row['store_id'];
                    $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCode();

                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . $pathInfo . "?___store=" . $storeCode);
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this solution looks interesting. Can anyone confirm it will work and not create other issues?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in Magento 1.7.  Here is a hack that worked for me.
It should work for a two language store with store code in URL

in var/www/html/shop1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php

remove this line

```
 // $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl(). '/' . $this->getRequestPath();
```

and add these:

```
 $storecode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
 if ($storecode='en')
 {
    $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl(). '/'.$storecode.'/' . $this->getRequestPath();
 }
 else
 {
    $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl(). '/' . $this->getRequestPath();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

guys. For this error there is magento module. It have rewrite 2 models
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fix-404-error-in-language-switching.html